# Doxygen and License/Copyright informations

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I have a simple question which I could not find digging Google.

I'm moving my project's documentation from **phpDoc** to **Doxygen**, but I don't know how to write *@license* and *@copyright* together.

In my conception, *@copyright* is designed for my "company" (not real yet :P) name and *@license* the way of what I'm developing can be used: one of many CreativeCommons combinations, GNU, MIT, BSD, "under license"...

Comment: I'm interested to know what's motivating the move from phpDoc to Doxygen? We've recently started using phpDoc, and I'm fairly happy with it; the new version 2 seems reasonably quick and configurable (the new-look phpDoc website is shocking though!).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Building on [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12366061/894042), you can use the `\par` command to create a block similar to the built in `\copyright` command. For example, an alias like:

```
ALIASES += "license=@par License:\n"
```

Will allow this comment:

```
/** My main function.

    \copyright Copyright 2012 Chris Enterprises. All rights reserved.
    \license This project is released under the GNU Public License.
*/
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

to produce this output:

[image]

Note that with this solution, a blank line is not required before `\license`, and that the `{}` syntax is not required. This is also less likely to cause problems if you attempt to generate documentation for formats other than HTML.

Comment: Very useful, thanks! I played around with this a bit and came up with several additional formatting options to produce license output. I threw the Doxyfile snippet and a source code file with examples into a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mzipay/2c16253c401f11887c560f51586e7bd6

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I agree with your distinction between copyright and license information, it seems that doxygen doesn't offer separate commands for these. In fact, from the documentation of the [`\author` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdauthor) the command `\copyright` is used to indicate license information.

There are (at least) two possible things you can do here:

1. Simply combine the copyright and license information into the argument of the `\copyright` command:

   ```
   /** My main function.

       \copyright Copyright 2012 Chris Enterprises. All rights reserved.
       This project is released under the GNU Public License.
   */
   int main(void){
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   This generates the HTML

   [image: Screenshot of the documentation generated by doxygen using first solution]

   This is almost certainly the easiest thing you can do.
2. Alternatively, the HTML which is written to produce the above image is

   ```
   <dl class="section copyright"><dt>Copyright</dt><dd>Copyright 2012 Chris Enterprises. All rights reserved. This project is released under the GNU Public License. </dd></dl>
   ```

   We can make use of this to [define a new command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html) called, say, `license`, which behaves in a similar way to the `copyright` command. Placing the following into the `ALIASES` field of the doxygen configuration file

   ```
   ALIASES += license{1}="<dl class=\"section copyright\"><dt>License</dt><dd>\1 </dd></dl>"
   ```

   and changing the above documentation block to

   ```
   /** My main function.

       \copyright Copyright 2012 Chris Enterprises. All rights reserved.

       \license{This project is released under the GNU Public License.}
   */
   ```

   we get the doxygen generated output

   [image: Screenshot of the documentation generated by doxygen using second solution]

   Note that there are a couple of quirks in this second solution: there must be a blank line preceding the `\license{...}` command and the `\license` command must wrap it's argument in curly braces. You can optionally do this with the `\copyright` command, but the commands with arguments defined via `ALIASES` these must have braces.

Comment: The second solution looks better, however I could not use it.  

I thought it could be something with "spacement policy" in my Doc Block so I replaced it with yours and I got the same result.  

I'm receiving three <p> filled, respectively, with: The <dt> definition, the text inside curly braces and a single quote.  

Is there any additional configuration I should enable? Before run Doxygen I made a few fine-tuning and, maybe, I disabled something accidentally.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Try running doxygen with the default configuration file. Also, a number of recent questions have been solved by updating doxygen to the latest versions. Perhaps you could try that.

Comment: I started with Doxygen a few days ago. I have the lastest version :)

Comment: Why do you say "copyright" twice?